# Placing Thumbnails instead of Text in a Nav Menu (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

first of all I'm very new to php and html overall, but I have a function to find the parent of a page and retrieve all of the children of that page and display it as a footer menu. What I am trying to do is display the page thumbnail (featured image) as the hyperlink to that page instead of the the title of that page. Right now this is the code that I have that corresponds to this menu:

```js
// Get Top Ancestor
function get_top_ancestor_id() {
 
 global $post;
 
 if ($post->post_parent) {
  $ancestors = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
  return $ancestors[0];
 
 }
 
 return $post->ID;
 
}
```

```css
div.foot-wrapper {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
 flex-direction: row;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border: 1px dotted #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="foot-wrapper"> 
  <nav class="site-nav-child children-links clearfix">
   
    <ul>
     <?php 
      
     $args = array(
      'child_of' => get_top_ancestor_id(),
      'title_li' => ''
     );
      
     ?>
     
     <?php wp_list_pages($args);?>
      
    </ul>
     
  </nav>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, spent too many hours looking up answers and finding nothing relevant to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

if your question was to add a thumbnail and make it clickable to the category, here i think this would help, run within the loop.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
```